# Running 2 small cartridge heater and 2 Solid State Relay (SSR) with 1 PID Controller

Tags: microcontroller, wiring, solid-state-relay, pid-controller, bad-wiring

I wanted to run a heating setup that processes optical fiber for tapering and making couplers (I am in photonics). I aim to reach 810C of temperature, whereas I am getting only 780C. Currently I use:

1. One PID controller loop - having 1 SSR and one cartridge heater sensed by a 1 K-type probe.
2. My question is - I wanted to add another cartridge heater, and I need an SSR to drive it. However, I wonder how to run both (heater with SSR) using 1 PID controller? Is there any circuit diagram or drawing to refer to? Do I need the wiring of both the relays combined together together at PID terminals?

I appreciate your time and effort in helping out!